# Neo4j: Schema index lookup slower than legacy indexes?

Tags: java, performance, neo4j

I'm currently migrating some older Neo4j-related code to the new Neo4j 2.0.0 beta. I think the new schema indexes are a nice feature in a range of cases so I wanted to change my code to use them when possible.
But before doing that I thought, I'd like to be sure I wouldn't get worse performance. So I wrote a small test. And surprisingly, the schema indexes consistently perform worse than the legacy indexes when it comes to lookups. But before jumping to conclusions, I'd like to share my test with you so you can tell me whether I did something illegal or the results are only this way due to the simpleness of the test case or similar issues. Also, you could try it yourself and confirm/reject my observation. Because as it stands now, I would rather stick to legacy indexes, they even have some nicer properties when used from within Java code (you can't create two indexes with the same name but will just get back the existing one, where a schema index would throw an exception, on index search/get results you have the ".single()" method where with schema indexes I seemingly have to use the iterator...)

Below my code. I just tested by commenting out the calls to one type of index - legacy or schema - and then running the whole thing a few times. I tried it with various values of N, ranging from 1000 as shown here to 60000, always with the same relative result that legacy indexes do a significant faster lookup. Obviously, my use case are a lot of nodes, each with a unique ID and I require the lookup of a whole range of nodes as quick as possible where I only have the nodes' IDs.

My question is: Are legacy indexes indeed faster and I should stick to them if this is a major issue for me or am I doing something wrong or this is a known issue and will be worked out during the beta and be solved in the release? Thank you!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Label;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.ResourceIterator;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.index.Index;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.schema.IndexDefinition;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.schema.Schema;
import org.neo4j.tooling.GlobalGraphOperations;

enum labels implements Label {
    term
}

public class Neo4jIndexPerformanceTest {
    private static int N = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("tmp/graph.db"));
        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("tmp/graph.db");
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            int i = 0;
            for (Node n : GlobalGraphOperations.at(graphDb).getAllNodes())
                i++;
            System.out.println("Number of nodes: " + i);
        }
//      createLegacyIndex(graphDb);
//      searchLegacyIndex(graphDb);
        createSchemaIndex(graphDb);
        searchSchemaIndex(graphDb);
        graphDb.shutdown();
    }

    private static void searchSchemaIndex(GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            IndexDefinition index = graphDb.schema().getIndexes(labels.term).iterator().next();
            graphDb.schema().awaitIndexOnline(index, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                ResourceIterator<Node> iterator = graphDb.findNodesByLabelAndProperty(labels.term, "id", "schema:" + i).iterator();
                if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Node n = iterator.next();
                } 
                iterator.close();
            }
        }
        time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
        System.out.println("Searching schema index took: " + time + " ms");
    }

    private static void searchLegacyIndex(GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            Index<Node> index = graphDb.index().forNodes("terms");
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                ResourceIterator<Node> iterator = index.get("id", "legacy:" + i).iterator();
                if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Node single = iterator.next();
                }
                iterator.close();
                // if (single == null)
                // throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
        }
        time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
        System.out.println("Searching legacy index took: " + time + " ms");

    }

    private static void createSchemaIndex(GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {
        Schema schema = null;
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            schema = graphDb.schema();
            boolean e = false;
            for (IndexDefinition id : graphDb.schema().getIndexes()) {
                e = true;
            }
            if (!e)
                schema.indexFor(labels.term).on("id").create();
            tx.success();
        }
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                Node n = graphDb.createNode(labels.term);
                n.setProperty("id", "schema:" + i);
            }

            time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
            schema.awaitIndexesOnline(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            tx.success();
            System.out.println("Creating schema index took: " + time + " ms");
        }
    }

    private static void createLegacyIndex(GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            Index<Node> index = graphDb.index().forNodes("terms");

            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                Node n = graphDb.createNode(labels.term);
                n.setProperty("id", "legacy:" + i);
                index.add(n, "id", n.getProperty("id"));
            }

            time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
            tx.success();
            System.out.println("Creating legacy index took: " + time + " ms");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code and indeed the schema index implementation is not as fast as the legacy. But I found the reason and it's a simple mistake in the implementation around the index, not the index itself. I tried locally to just fix those mistakes and they are precisely as performant, the legacy and schema indexes.

So it's a matter of doing a proper fix and I can only hope that it makes it into the 2.0 release.

Comment: Hi! Wow, isn't that an insight! Thank you a lot. Question is whether the Neo4j guys are aware of the issue. Since you know how to change it, would you mind to open a respective issue in the Neo4j Github repository? If you could point out the places to change, I would hope they can include this in the release easily. Also, I'd be gladful if you could post a link to the issue here so I can watch the progress on this. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: I'm considered one of the "neo4j guys" btw :) and it's tracked on an internal issue list. There isn't a public issue created for every issue internally worked on, so creating a public one wouldn't receive as much attention anyway. I'm sure it will get attention before 2.0 is out.

Comment: Oh, that's right, I already thought your avatar looked familiar :-) Then I will just go for schema indexes and hope everything will be alright in the release. Thanks a bunch for your feedback!

Comment: any updates on this issue? - I came right now to the same conclusion with neo4j 2.0.1 and was wondering, whether there is a different option to access the index instead of #findNodesByLabelAndProperty? (which I suppose to be the way it is, or?)